# Go from "search" field directly to an anchor in Firefox just pressing enter?

Tags: firefox, search, plugins

Suppose I'm in the Firefox's "search box" at the bottom of the screen.

The searched string is an anchor in a page I'm using. This searched string is an anchor, that I have to take my hands off the keyboard and use the mouse to select this anchor.

Is possible to just press enter to acomplish this, or maybe a shortcut in this context? A plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash / key and the apostrophe ' key both open the Quick Find bar too.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that... it even works in iframes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the “Quick Find” feature: when you type, the first instance of the searched text is selected and if it's a link, you can access it by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To enable it go to Tools → Options → Advanced → check Type to search text on page.

Comment: I tried and it's not working... which firefox version are you using? I'm using 3.0.9 (can't upgrade... :(

Comment: I'm using the newest stable – 3.6.3. Have you tried Hello's solution?

Comment: Yes, interesting, I didn't know that! Anyways, thanks to your suggestion!